# How to add a value for CC or reply-to in each new message

Tags: mu4e

I use `mu4e`. I would like to add a hook called with a new message, such as adding a certain value in CC or in Reply-to. I found no guidance online and no functions starting with `mu4e` and ending with `hook` (only `mu4e~compose-register-message-save-hooks`).

How can I add a header automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Compose-hooks.html) has one such example:

```
(add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook
  (defun my-add-bcc ()
    "Add a Bcc: header."
    (save-excursion (message-add-header "Bcc: me@example.com\n"))))
```

This `mu4e-compose-mode-hook` does not show as a function because it's a variable. Do `C-h v RET mue4*hook` and you will see many matches.